# Definition of smooth morphism of schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In Wedhorn's and Görtz's book, a morphism $f: X \to Y$ is said to be smooth of relative dimension $d$ when for every $x \in X$, there exists affine open neighborhoods $U$ of $x$ and $V = \operatorname{Spec} R$ of $y=f(x)$ such that $f(U) \subseteq V$, and an open immersion of $R$-schemes $j: U \hookrightarrow \operatorname{Spec} R[T_1, \dots, T_n]/(g_1, \dots, g_{n-d})$ such that the matrix $\left (\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial T_j}(x)\right )$ has rank $n-d$.

In Bosch's book, $f$ is smooth of relative dimension $d$ if for every $x \in X$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and an $Y$-morphism $j:U \to W \subseteq \mathbb{A}_Y^n$ (here, $\mathbb{A}^n_Y = \underline{\operatorname{Spec}}_Y \mathscr{O}_Y[T_1, \dots, T_n]$) giving rise to a closed immersion from $U$ over an open subscheme $W \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n_Y$ satisfying:

If $\mathcal{I} \subseteq \mathscr{O}_W$ is the ideal correspondent to $j$, then there are $n-d$ sections $g_1, \dots g_{n-d}$ generating $\mathcal{I}$ in a neighborhood of $z = j(x)$ and such that the matrix $\left(\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial t_j}(z)\right)$ has rank $n-d$, where $t_i$ are the coordinate functions of $\mathbb{A}^n_Y$.

To be honest, I can't quite make sense of Bosch's definition: what does $\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial t_j}$ even mean, given that the $t_j$ are global sections and the $g_i$ are sections on a neighborhood of $z$, and, thus, not necessarily polynomials. Am I missing something? How can I prove that these two definitions are equivalent? I can sort of see how Bosch's definition imply Wedhorn's and Görtz's, if I squint. Can someone help me?

Comment: Given that the $g_i$ are sections in a neighborhood, they are rational functions, and you can differentiate rational functions just as easily as polynomials (well, you have to use the quotient rule instead of just the product rule).